# No EntityManager Error in Play Framework 2.5 recieving data in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.5

using the play Framework 2.5 for Java

I want to create an application that consumes data from ActiveMQ and from this message received executes one hibernate query to database and store one object User.
I had simplified my consumer class in order to create one object there an make the call to the persistence at the same time.

my Problem comes when I call the persistence from the thread (or invoke another class) that receives the measurement. Then the EntityManager is not present there and I can not create a new one, or be frank I dont know to make it in Play.

```
package controllers;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import models.User;
import play.Logger;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;

public class MessageConsumerController implements Runnable, ExceptionListener {
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "miguelTopic";
    private static Thread consumerService;

    public static synchronized void initService() {
        Logger.info("Message Consumer initialized");
        MessageConsumerController MessageConsumer = new MessageConsumerController();
        if (consumerService != null) {
            Logger.info("STOPPING MessageConsumer thread.");
            consumerService.interrupt();
        }
        Logger.info("Starting MessageConsumer thread.");
        consumerService = new Thread(MessageConsumer);
        consumerService.setDaemon(true);
        consumerService.setName("MessageConsumer Service");
        consumerService.start();
        Logger.info("MessageConsumer thread started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin",
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");

            Logger.info("Creating ActiveMQ connection");
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            connection.setExceptionListener(this);
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            Logger.info("Connecting to topic " + TOPIC_NAME);
            Destination destination = session.createTopic(TOPIC_NAME);

            Logger.info("Creating consumer");
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Logger.info("Wait for messages...");
                Message message = consumer.receive();

                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    String text = textMessage.getText();
                    Logger.info("Received: " + text);
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setId(555);
                    user.setName("miguel");
                    user.setTime_of_start("time");
                    Logger.info("insert user");

                    //JPAApi jpa = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);

                    JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
                    JPA.em().persist(user); // 
                    JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();



                } else {
                    Logger.info("Received: " + message.getClass().getSimpleName());
                }

            }
            Logger.info("Message consumer interrupted.");
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                Logger.info("Message Consumer thread interrupted.");
            } else {
                Logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void onException(JMSException ex) {
        Logger.error("JMS Exception occured.  Shutting down client.");
        Logger.error("ErrorCode=" + ex.getErrorCode() + " , " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

}
```

I had tried injecting JPaapi , and many more different things but I am nearly new to Play Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Play Framework I recommend using Akka actors instead of the traditional java Threads. It may seem complicated at first, however it will save a lot of debugging time once you get the hang of it. Akka is already integrated in Play so it should not be a problem.

Now, regarding your Entity Manager. First, make sure you have the java JDBC in your sbt build file: `libraryDependencies += javaJdbc`

Next, in your configuration file make sure you have the default DS configured: `db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS` as well as a persistance unit (more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA )

Now, your controller (I don't see the actual controller in the code you posted) must have `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Hello Petre, I forgot to mention in this project that persistence is working perfectly in other classes but the problem is a get not an entity manager when I need from the thread.

Comment: How is your class created and the thread started? Up until now I always used @Inject to inejct the needed class and I had a DAO that dealt with the DB side.
You can try using JPA.withTransaction(). Maybe that will help.

Comment: `JPA.withTransaction(() -> { // your code that deals with the DB});` or with JPAapi it is `jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> { // again, your code });`